# PHP resize image from FTP

Tags: php, ftp, gdi

I need resize Image from FTP like /images/1_2.jpg. I need to load it to imagecreatefromjpeg();. Now my script looks like this.

```
$file = "images/1_2.jpg";

$imagesize = getimagesize($file);

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);


$width = 70;
$height = 100;

$img2 = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

imagecopyresampled($img2, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $imagesize[0], $imagesize[1]);

imagejpeg($img2, "images_mini/1_2.jpg");
```

My problem is that images don't upload to FTP, its shows me everything is ok but i can't find images on FTP.

Comment: And your problem is... ?

Comment: My problem is that images don't upload to ftp, its shows me everythink is ok but i can't find images on ftp.

Comment: Check folder permissions.

Comment: Already done, every folder is 777

Comment: But i must remind that I need to load image and manipulate with image from ftp.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have it, just only bad converted variable, i using cross languages now for application so it is dificult to check everythink. Thank you anyway.